# Redis matching keys using SCAN with Glob pattern to get collection of items within a namespace

Tags: redis, glob

I have a redis data structure like so:

```
practice:1:patient:{UUID}:reports:{UUID}
practice:1:patient:{UUID}:reports:{UUID}:notes:{id}
practice:1:patient:{UUID}:reports:{UUID}:notes:{id}:fieldValue:{id}
practice:1:patient:{UUID}
practice:1:patient:{UUID}:variables
practice:1:patient:{UUID}:documents
```

I'm trying to query for specifically `patient:{UUID}` keys but it's proving difficult with glob pattern matching.

1. Should I create a set `practice:1:patients` with the patient keys added to it?
2. Is there a valid glob pattern that would isolate that namespace?
3. Is there a better way to query for collections (e.g. to also apply to the reports, notes, etc.) / would I have to create a set for every namespace that contains the keys for that collection?

Answer (score 1):

Scanning the entire keyspace to retrieve a few keys is inefficient - use a different data structure to store the patient data (e.g. a Hash) and/or Sets (your 1 and 3) to perform fast lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I ended up creating a sorted set based on properties I was going to sort for, e.g. patient:lastname, patient:firstname, etc. What would be a valid use case for SCAN (over the entire keyspace)?

Comment: A background housekeeping or analytical process can benefit from SCAN, for example.